# How to receive data from showBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

I found a solution with Navigator.pop(context, data) in showModalBottomSheet

this is solution

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, AppBar().preferredSize.height, 0, 0),
                          child: CountryPicker(
                            countryCodes: countryCodes,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ).then((value) {
                      setState(() {
                        countryCodeIndex = value;
                      });
                    });
```

but i can't use method then in showBottomSheet

this is error that i got

```
The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'PersistentBottomSheetController'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'then
```

How i can receive data from showBottomSheet

Comment: I can't use showModalBottomSheet, bottomSheet must be same size as screen. if there is a way how i can make modalBottomSheet same size as screen, i will use showModalBottomSheet

Comment: If you set the width of the returned widget of showModalBottomSheet's builder function it can also take same as screen size. E.g. `Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, child: ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `showModalBottomSheet`you can just use `then()` or `await`

When you have to use `showBottomSheet()` it returns a `PersistentBottomSheetController` that has a property `closed` of type Future<T> that can also be used with `then()`or `await`. Check API documentation on that: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PersistentBottomSheetController-class.html

Edit: I did some further research: Seems like showBottomSheet is not working as expected. There's an issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66837) where it's stated that `Navigator.pop(context)` with data is not working...
So if possible I would recommend to use ``